# Any way to automatically close the hamburger menu with JQuery?

Tags: anchor, hamburger-menu, elementor

The class "elementor-active" is removed after click but the menu remains open.

```
<div class="elementor-menu-toggle elementor-active" data-target="#menu-0dc8207">
    <i class="eicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span class="menu-toggle-title"></span>
</div>

<nav id="menu-0dc8207" class="elementor-nav-menu--canvas mp-menu">
    <ul id="menu-2-0dc8207" class="nav-menu--canvas">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1408"><a href="#house-description-id">overview</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1337"><a href="#interior-custom-id">interior</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1335"><a href="#apartments-plans-id">plan</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1340"><a href="#gallery-custom-id">galery</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1431"><a href="#footer-kontakt-custom-id">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

using in functions.php

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_hamburger', 999 );
    function change_hamburger() { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery( '.nav-menu--canvas .menu-item a' ).on("click", function(){
                jQuery('.elementor-menu-toggle').removeClass("elementor-active");
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php }
?>
```

Basically, when the user presses one of the links in the menu on the mobile phone, the menu remains open. What I want to achieve is to make the menu close after pressing one of the links on mobile. How is that possible with jQuery?